# Configure IPython (i.e. Jupyter) History with Custom Information

Tags: python, directory, ipython

I want to customize the way IPython saves history. IPython creates a sqlite3 database that contains the history of typed commands, but I want to customize it so that will allow me to save additional information, such as the current working directory when the line of code was executed. A table of this would like like:

```
Command       Directory
import sys     /Users/home
import os      /Users/home
os.chdir("~/data")    /Users/home
data = open("input_file", 'r').read()   /Users/home/data
```

Also, I want to have this done as each line is executed (as opposed to saving as at the end of a session manually).

Does anyone know how to do this? IPython does not seem to have an configurable options that allow you to add custom information to history that I could find on their documentation, or looking at option available in `config HistoryManager` within IPython

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around, I figured it out. The key is to modify the IPython code that runs the IPython interactive shell. Within the script `interactiveshell.py` (for me, this is located in `~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core`), put the following block of code in the script `interactiveshell.py`, at the very beginning of the function run_cell (this is approximately lines 2617):

```
#location of command
cwd=os.getcwd() 
file_1=open("~/.custom_history_file.txt", "a")
#time of command
showtime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
showtime=showtime.rstrip()
#ignore those lines with just empty spaces
if raw_cell.strip():
    print (raw_cell,file=file_1,sep="",end="") 
    print ("#Command Info:\t","cwd: ",cwd,"\tdate: ",showtime,file=file_1)
    #print("\n",file=file_1)
    #print (raw_cell,cwd,sep="\t",file=file_1) 
file_1.close()
```

At the top of the script, put the following:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
```

Now as you use IPython, your custom history file will be filled with the python commands and the information